# Overlaying video with text - ffmpeg speed

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, overlay, drawtext

I'm developing an app that has a functionality similar to Snapchat's, in which you can add text to an existing video and save it on your phone.

I got this to work using ffmpeg's "-drawtext" filter. The problem is that I'm getting a noticable delay (20 seconds or so) when adding text to videos, even though they are not too big (around 10 seconds length).

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to reduce this delay? Taking Snapchat as reference, they overlay high quality videos with text with little to no delay.

I've read about extracting the video's frames and overlaying them manually, but shouldn't that take longer?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the ffmpeg command you're using?

Comment: That's just the filterchain. What's the full command.

Comment: @Mulvya 

My bad. 

'-i path/to/videoTempFile.mp4 -vf "drawbox=x=Z:y=Z:w=Z:h=Z:color=black@0.4:t=h, drawtext=fontsize=Z:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fon‌​tcolor=white:text=TE‌​XT:x=Z:y=Z" path/to/outputVideo.mp4'

Comment: Add `-preset ultrafast` and check.

Comment: @Mulvya Still takes around 15 seconds. Full command below. Video lasts 10 secs at 30fps.

-i /data/user/0/com.app.app/cache/temp-1364046389.mp4 -vf "drawbox=x=0:y=0.3623188*ih:w=iw:h=67.5:color=black@0.4:t=h, drawtext=fontsize=42.66667:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=white:text='prueba tiempo2':x=(w-tw)/2:y=0.3623188*h:" /storage/emulated/0/Movies/TestVideos/test106-e709-4efe-a7cd-834d51313e6c.mp4 -preset ultrafast

Comment: The preset has to come after the input filename and before the output name.

Comment: @Mulvya That reduced the delay by half. Thanks a lot! One more question: the drawbox filter adds an extra 3-4 seconds to the process. Is this normal?

Comment: Depends on total duration and processor speed, but sounds normal.

Comment: Show the complete console output of your command: if it shows `cpu capabilities: none` then it will be slow, but it can possibly be fixed. If your player supports softsubs perhaps you can skip the costly encoding process.